# Docs Apps Script ReplaceText: how to match line break <br>?

Tags: regex, google-apps-script, google-docs

In a google Docs document, the normal effect of hitting the return key is to create a new paragraph, not to insert a line break character in a paragraph.

But Text paragraphs can have line breaks in them (for instance, when they are pasted from other sources).  I have verified this by downloading the document as html; the relevant paragraphs have br tags inside them.  Also, the line-beginnings and line-endings with these breaks do not match regExp ^ and $ in the replaceText command.

What I would like to know is how to match these line breaks with regular expressions in replaceText.  The obvious ideas do not work:

```
'\r' 
'\\r'
'\n'
'\\n'
'\\\\n'
'\\\\r'
'\\\\\\\\n'
"\\[\\\\n\\\\r\\]\\+"
'< br >'
'< BR >'
```

This is for use in an extension that eliminates line breaks in selected text.  So far it merges paragraphs, which suffices so long as there are no line breaks in the paragraphs themselves.

Thanks for any help!

Mark

Comment: what would be the replacing string for all these tags that you want to use?

Comment: Thanks for replying KRR.  I just want to replace line breaks with spaces.  I managed to do it, but only by examining the ascii code of each character (if it's 10 or 13, replace with a space).  The RegExp functionality in replaceString doesn't match ascii 13 (carriage-return) as `\r`.  This is clearly a bug; the string `'\\r'` should produce a regexp matching what Docs represents internally as having ascii code 13.  Instead, it matches that character (13) as a non-whitespace.

Comment: If someone knows how to report a bug, please do so or tell me how.

Comment: @MarkCrimmins The Google Apps Script bugtracker is located at https://code.google.com/p/google-apps-script-issues/issues/list - you can submit an issue there if you're so inclined.

Comment: @MarkCrimmins Was this reported and/or ever resolved?

Comment: @Karl_S Reported but never resolved, as far as I know.